# Can "equipping" a set with structure be given a precise definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, foundations

An algebraic structure such a group can be formally defined as an ordered pair $(G,\cdot)$, where $G$ is a set and $\cdot$ is a binary operation on $G$ satisfying various axioms. This is not the only way to define groups: for instance, a group may be defined as an ordered quadruple $(G,\cdot,^{-1},e)$, where $\cdot$ is a binary operation (on $G$), $^{-1}$ is a unary operation, and $e$ is a constant; this definition is more in line with universal algebra.

However, my experience is that in practice, algebraists tend not to use either definition in their mental picture of groups. Instead, a group is described more informally as a set "equipped", "endowed", or "enriched" with some extra structure. The same goes for other algebraic structures of any kind. This way of thinking is reflected by how, in practice, algebraic structures are almost always referred to by the name of their underlying set.

Usually, the formal way to make sense of this "equipping" is just to define algebraic structures as $n$-tuples with certain properties. But I wonder if there is a way of defining them which feels closer to how they are actually conceived of. In particular, I would like to be able to speak of "elements of a group/ring/vector space" directly. In the usual formalism, that phrase has to be interpreted as a shorthand for "elements of *the underlying set* of a group/ring/vector space"; can this be avoided?

Comment: If you’re willing to think categorically then any category with a faithful functor to the category of sets can be viewed as a category of sets “with extra structure”

Comment: You might be interested in [stuff, structure and properties](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property) at the nlab, which has some discussion of this issue.

Comment: Any book on mathematical logic defines what a structure is rigorously.

Answer (score 7):

As an exercise in precisely precise language this is an interesting question (though not in the context of actually communicating mathematics with other people, where "elements of an object" is completely understood even if formally the object is a tuple rather than the set).

One way of resolving it would be to define a "group" (for example) as the set $G$ while defining a "group structure" as the quadruple $(G,\cdot,{}^{-1},e)$. "Equipping a set with a group structure" would then mean finding a group-structure quadruple whose first element is the set.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

In category theory, groups and sets are organized in categories $\mathrm{Grp}$ and $\mathrm{Set}$, respectively. A set $X$ can be identified with a functor $X:1\to\mathrm{Set}$ and a group with a functor $G:1\to\mathrm{Grp}$, where $1$ is the terminal category. There is a functor $U:\mathrm{Grp}\to\mathrm{Set}$ which sends any group to its underlying set. In this context, equipping a set $X$ with a group structure is the same as finding a lift of $X:1\to\mathrm{Set}$ to $\mathrm{Grp}$ along $U$. I.e. finding a functor $G:1\to\mathrm{Grp}$ such that $UG=X$. Usually we allow for isomorphisms of functors instead of equality, so we can replace the last condition with $UG\simeq X$.

Comment: I thought about something along these lines when I was writing my question, and I do like this idea, but I have the following quibble. Surely the objects of $\mathsf{Grp}$ still have to be defined precisely in some way, and won't that ultimately force us to adopt the "tuple" definition?

Comment: In case there is a confusion, my last comment wasn't rhetorical: I am genuinely interested in how someone with a categorical mindset would answer my objection. But of course you are not obliged to reply!

Comment: @Joe Sure, well, would need to define the category of groups in some way or another. Admittedly I was addressing the question in the title more than the body of your question. My post doesn't address at all your desire to be able to say that a group has elements directly.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't think it was rhetorical, I just postponed answering, sorry about that. About your obection, probably someone with a categorical mind would say that your objection is a consequence of submitting yourself to the use of sets. Categorically, it doesn't even matter how you define your groups as long as you obtain an equivalent category. Then you could define an element of a group $G$ as a group morphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G$.

Comment: Thanks, that does help. One thing I'm not sure about is how an element of a group $G$ can be identified with a group morphism $\mathbb Z\to G$. I don't quite see the connection.

Answer (score 2):

You have a forgetful functor from $Grp$ (or $Ring$ or whatever) to $Set$, and a free functor adjoint to it.

This free functor from $Set$ to $Grp$ will be monadic and will admit an algebra, which will recover your original group. So up to the embedding of the free functor, the algebra is what equips your set with structure. (But by quotienting a free structure instead of adding stuff.)

Edit: A nice thing about this is that it generalizes to other forgetful functors. e.g: you may consider adding structure to a monoid or group so it becomes a ring, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly "equipping" a set $G$ with additional structure could be construed categorically as a map/functor/whatever from the category with one object, the set $G$, and only the identity self-map morphism, to whatever ("richer") category we want?

(This does not seem to require that $G$ be a set, though the ramifications of this non-requirement are completely unclear to me at the moment.)